# How do I avoid restarting iPython parallel clusters every time I restart the Jupyter kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I am running iPython Parallel.

Every time I restart the main notebook kernel, I have to restart the cluster as well. Without doing so, I get a `NoEnginesRegistered` error (in other words, the directview cannot see the engines).

This is quite tedious and error prone for long running tasks. What's the reason this is the case, and how can I keep the cluster going despite what happens to the notebook kernel?

Comment: Is this happening even though you start the cluster from the commandline with ipcluster (or ipcontroller+ipengine) or are you using the notebook extension to start a cluster?